# Avoid nesting loops in bash inheriting input source?

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
while read LINE; do
    if [[ "$LINE" == "ask" ]]; then
        read USR_RESPONSE
    fi
done < a.txt
```

but cannot figure out how to make inner read read from stdin. I tried combinations of:

```
while read LINE; do
    if [[ "$LINE" == "ask" ]]; then
        read USR_RESPONSE (<0) (<&0) 
    fi
done (< a.txt) (3<a.txt)
```

but none seem to work; (3< a.txt) instead of separating file descriptors, acts so the outer loop reads from stdin, not what i want. Any tried variants in inner read have simply no effect, although no mistakes in execution time. How do I make stop inheriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read -u 10 LINE; do
    if [[ "$LINE" == "ask" ]]; then
        read USR_RESPONSE
    fi
done 10< a.txt
```

Comment: I found out the hard way that `read -u` isn't portable, so I tend to recommend e.g. `read LINE <&10` instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Indeed. But since it is a ```bash``` tagged question, I guess it is OK to have that as answer, even if not portable. Your alternative is a good one anyway.